# Having issues using MUI collapsable table and handling props HELPP

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hey guys i was having a issue with this react component

basically what im trying to do is use MUI to create a collapsible table, each row has a day of the week and when you open it, it lists the data of a call timing

im fetching the data in app.js from my flask api and setting it to a state called "calls"

the state is passed as props to the above component

the issue im having is using the createData() to get the data from calls so that the collapsible table component can iterate over it and display the data

```
    const [callData, setCallData] = useState()
    useEffect(()=>{
      if(!calls) return;
      setCallData(calls);
    },[calls]);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <TableRow sx={{ "& > *": { borderBottom: "unset" } }}>
            <TableCell>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="expand row"
                size="small"
                onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
              >
                {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
              </IconButton>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              {callData.day}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
              <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
                  <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                    History
                  </Typography>
                  <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                    <TableHead>
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>volunteer Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Phone Number</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Senior Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Phone Number</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Time</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Day</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Phone Line</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                      {callData.data.map((rowData) => (
                        <TableRow key={callData.day}>
                          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                            {callData.day}
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{callData.volunteerName}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{callData.volunteerPhoneNumber}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{callData.seniorName}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{callData.seniorPhoneNumber}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{callData.Time}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{callData.day}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{callData.phoneNumber}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      ))}
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                </Box>
              </Collapse>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }

    function createData(day, callData) {
        console.log(callData)
        if(!createData) return;
        for(let i = 0; i < callData.day[day].length; i++) {
            return {
                day,
                data: callData.day[day],
            };
        }
    }

    Row.propTypes = {
      row: PropTypes.shape({
        data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
          PropTypes.shape({
            volunteerName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            volunteerPhoneNumber: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            seniorName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            seniorPhoneNumber: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            Time: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            day: PropTypes.string,
            phoneNumber: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
          })
        ).isRequired,
      })
    };

  

const rows = [
  createData("Monday", callData),
  createData("Tuesday"),
  createData("Wednesday"),
  createData("Thursday"),
  createData("Friday"),
];

export default function CollapsibleTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <Row key={row.day} row={row} />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is also a link to my repo if that helps!
https://github.com/Arhum2/CTW